# How I get the right linq statement for filter to arraylist values in my xml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, arraylist

I have two Arraylists and a xml file. I want to filter this xml file with a LINQ statement.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList ListOfNPSGroups = MyClass.ActiveDirectoryManager.GetGroupsInOUByValue(); //all groups from the xml

ArrayList ActiveUserList = MyClass.ActiveDirectoryManager.GetGroupmemberList(DOMAIN, Username, ListOfNPSGroups); //only the user groups

XDocument x = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\location.xml"));

IEnumerable<XElement> elements;

for (int i = 0; i < ActiveUserList.Count; i++)
{
    elements = x.Descendants("plant").Where( xe => (string)xe.Attribute("group") == ActiveUserList[i].ToString());

    foreach (XElement el in elements)
    {
        el.remove();
    }
}
```

My xml:

```
<plants>
  <plant id="DB" display=".testDB.." group="NPS_DB" />
  <plant id="EL" display=".testEL.." group="NPS_EL" />
  <plant id="IN" display="..testIN." group="NPS_IN" />
  <plant id="SB" display=".testSB.." group="NPS_SB" />
  <plant id="BL" display=".testBL.." group="NPS_BL" />
  <plant id="LS" display="..testLS.." group="NPS_LS" />
</plants>
```

For Example: I want if my User is only in the groups nps_db and nps_el that my xml updated to this:

```
  <plants>
      <plant id="DB" display=".testDB.." group="NPS_DB" />
      <plant id="EL" display=".testEL.." group="NPS_EL" />
    </plants>
```

but I think that my linq statement is wrong :/

Comment: Looks like you haven't even tried your `linq statement`? I guess so because you said this `I think that my linq statment is wrong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"NPS_DB", "NPS_IN"};

string xml = @"<plants>
                <plant id=""DB"" display="".testDB.."" group=""NPS_DB"" />
                <plant id=""EL"" display="".testEL.."" group=""NPS_EL"" />
                <plant id=""IN"" display=""..testIN."" group=""NPS_IN"" />
                <plant id=""SB"" display="".testSB.."" group=""NPS_SB"" />
                <plant id=""BL"" display="".testBL.."" group=""NPS_BL"" />
                <plant id=""LS"" display=""..testLS.."" group=""NPS_LS"" />
            </plants>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

xDoc.Root.Descendants()
          .Where(e => !list.Contains((string)e.Attribute("group")))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(s => s.Remove());
```

Comment: Can I bind this new xDoc to my DropDownList? I try this : drpLogLocation.DataSource = x;
                   drpLogLocation.DataBind(); x is my XDocument ..